# There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name associated with context path

Tags: java, struts2, xml-configuration, action-mapping

I am attaching my files. Kindly help me out.

I gave my url path as http://localhost:8080/Struts2Check/getTutorial.action

***struts-config.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

 <struts-config>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="getTutorial" class="org.tutorial.action.StrutsAction">

    <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/failiure.jsp</result>
    </action></package>
 </struts-config>
```

***error msg***

```
Feb 18, 2016 11:11:32 AM org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher warn
WARNING: Could not find action or result: /Struts2Check/getTutorial.action
There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [getTutorial] associated with context path [/Struts2Check]. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:185)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:37)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:554)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

2 things is to be verified. If your are using eclipse 2021 version then the struts.xml file should be in src/main/java/struts.xml. And other one is check whether the name of struts.xml is in captial, It should in small letter.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This worked out

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not defined namespaces for your struts application.

Basic configuration may look like this.

```
<package name="default">
    <action name="foo" class="mypackage.simpleAction">
        <result name="success" type="dispatcher">greeting.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="bar" class="mypackage.simpleAction">
        <result name="success" type="dispatcher">bar1.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>

<package name="mypackage1" namespace="/">
    <action name="moo" class="mypackage.simpleAction">
        <result name="success" type="dispatcher">moo.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>

<package name="mypackage2" namespace="/barspace">
    <action name="bar" class="mypackage.simpleAction">
        <result name="success" type="dispatcher">bar2.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

Where `namespace="/"` defines the default namespace to look for.

Comment: I was just following the steps mentioned in a struts tutorial video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f46WEeM8HTA&list=PLB7BB551126EDD5E0 . In tat video he did the same and it worked for him

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong tag  in the Struts configuration file. It should be `<struts>`. And the name of the file should be `struts.xml`. This file should be on classpath i.e. in the `WEB-INF/classes` folder. There should also be an action class.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="getTutorial" class="org.tutorial.action.StrutsAction">
           <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
           <result name="error">/failure.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```